# How to identify moment something executed in Flame graph in DevTools?

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools, devtools, react-fiber, react-16

I'm using React 16 (Fiber engine) and need to see/identify specific moment in Main thread section to see what is happening after it.

Thus I come up with idea to put some code that will create some spike there and will enable me to see exact spot on the graph where something has started to happen.

**How to identify moment something executed in Flame graph in DevTools?**

Answer (score 0):

You may call some named function with fancy name and find it with `Ctrl/Cmd+F` there.